# Fade in and out when scrolling with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein

I want to show a div every time an amount of pixels are scrolled, and fade it out after some more scrolling. I found out some logic but, there is a conflict in the end,the div is fading in again, as I am telling every time scroll is > 250 it will fade in.
How can I solve it?

```
$('#1').hide();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) { //use `this`, not `document`
    $('#1').fadeIn();
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1250) { //use `this`, not `document`
    $('#1').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the element only if scrollTop value is less than or equal to `1250`.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 1250){
   $('#1').fadeIn();
}
```

---

Although you can use **[`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to stop the previous animation.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1250) 
       $('#1').stop().fadeOut();
    else
       $('#1').stop().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your logic is flawed. You need to cater for the cases where the `scrollTop` is not in the range of your current `if` conditions. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1250) {
    $('#1').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('#1').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8mwdoLtu/)

Note in the above example I had to change the `id` so that it did not begin with a number as that has issues in Chrome.